# How to make additional User properties available to the user object within the session callback?

Tags: next.js, prisma, next-auth

The user object within the session callback (https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks) contains an id, name, email, emailVerified and an image property. I added an additional property to the User model inside the schema.prisma file. So I wanted to ask if it is possible to access that property or make it accessable in some way without an extra CRUD operation. Maybe I should mention that the new property is a relational property:

Code shows new company property:

File: schema.prisma

```
model User {
  id            String    @id @default(cuid())
  name          String?
  email         String?   @unique
  emailVerified DateTime?
  image         String?
  accounts      Account[]
  sessions      Session[]
  company       Company?
}
```

Session callback which gets called every time the session is checked:

File: [...nextauth].ts

```
...

  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, user }) {
      session.user.id = user.id

      return session
    }
  }

...
```

As you can see I can access the user.id in the session callback but I would like to be able to access the new company property too !!!Without reading it from the database every time the session is checked!!!

PS: I persist sessions in a database.

Comment: did you try to use [session callback](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks#session-callback) ?

Comment: Exactly what I explained. The user object in the session callback only provides an id, name, email, emailVerified and an image property.

Comment: there is a workaround is to get the data from your database inside the `session` callback and add it to the `session` object, but the problem is that the database might be called on every session check which is not good.

Comment: That's why I said "make it accessable in some way WITHOUT an extra CRUD operation". But maybe it's impossible. I don't know exactly what is going on in the background.

Comment: ```callbacks.session``` is a closure, so you could fetch the companies outside the function and just return it along with the session object. When you then re-invoke ```callbacks.session```, the closure would persist your company data within the function, and always return it. You would only need one initial company fetch from the db then.

Answer (score 0):

The session object from the `useSession` function usually gets its data from the `getSessionAndUser` function in the adapter. In the case of prisma, you can find the adapter source in `node_modules/@next-auth/prisma/dist/index`. It's the same with MongoDB Adapter (`node_modules/@next-auth/dist/index`) and many other adapters.

```
async getSessionAndUser(sessionToken) {
   const userAndSession = await p.session.findUnique({
   where: { sessionToken }, 
   include: { user: true },
   });
   if (!userAndSession) return null;
   const { user, ...session } = userAndSession;
   return { user, session };
}
```

To make it clearer, I'd be using the Knex Adapter with mysql client that I stumbled on, so you can understand better what is going on:

```
getSessionAndUser: async (token: any) => {
  const userAndSession = await p(tables.Sessions)
  .join(tables.Users, "sessions.userId", "users.id")
  .where({ sessionToken: token })
  .select(
    "users.id as userId",
    "users.name",
    "users.email",
    "users.image",
    "users.emailVerified",
    "users.roleId",
    "sessions.id",
    "sessions.sessionToken",
    "sessions.expires"
  )

  if (!userAndSession.length) return null

  const { userId, name, email, image, emailVerified, id, expires, sessionToken, roleId } = userAndSession[0]
  const role = (await p(tables.Roles).where("id", roleId).first()).name

  return {
    user: {
      id: userId,
      name,
      email,
      emailVerified,
      image,
      role
    },
    session: {
      id,
      sessionToken,
      userId,
      expires
    }
  }
},
```

As you can see that the `getSessionAndUser` adapter function usually returns the user and the session properties where the session object gets its data. This has proven to be a better way to persist session data if you don't want to write queries in your `authOption` callbacks (like the session callback). Meanwhile, you may need to bring the adapter out of node_modules into your application as it is in my Knex Adapter case ([custom adapters](https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/creating-a-database-adapter).

You may also want to try writing your queries in the jwt callback and use an if statement to condition it's execution. According to the docs,

The arguments *user, account, profile and isNewUser* are only passed the first time this callback is called on a new session, after the user signs in. In subsequent calls, only token will be available.
The contents user, account, profile and isNewUser will vary depending on the provider and if you are using a database. You can persist data such as User ID, OAuth Access Token in this token. To expose it on the client side, check out the `session()` callback as well.

```
 ...
callbacks: {
  async jwt({ token, account, profile }) {
    // Persist the OAuth access_token and or the user id to the token right after signin
    if (account) {
      token.accessToken = account.access_token
      token.id = profile.id
      token.company = fetch companyProp() //this will be an async function you need to await. Since account will not be available subsequently after sign in, the query will not be executed more than once during session.
    }
    return token
  }
}
...
```

You can then use the session callback to persist the data.

```
...
callbacks: {
  async session({ session, token, user }) {
    // Send properties to the client, like an access_token and user id from a provider.
    session.accessToken = token.accessToken
    session.user.id = token.id
    session.company = token?.company

    return session
```

*tip
Use an if branch to check for the existence of parameters (apart from token). If they exist, this means that the callback is being invoked for the first time (i.e. the user is being signed in). This is a good place to persist additional data like an access_token in the JWT. Subsequent invocations will only contain the token parameter.*

You could check this issue:

[here](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/892)